# How to bind an enum to a playframework form?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an enum of the form:

```
object MatchFilterType extends Enumeration {
  type MatchFilterType = Value
  val gt = Value("gt")
  val lt = Value("lt")
  val eq = Value("eq")
}
```

Trying to create a form val in my controller:

```
 case class SearchRequest(mft: MatchFilterType, queryText: String, locations: List[String])

 val searchForm: Form[SearchRequest] = Form(
    mapping(
      "mft" -> ????????,
      "queryText" -> nonEmptyText,
      "locations" -> list(text)
    )(SearchRequest.apply)(SearchRequest.unapply)
  )
```

I am using play 2.6.x for this project.

How do I map my enumeration in my Form val?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create an implicit `Formatter` that uses the enums `withName` method which takes a string and turns it into an enum:

```
implicit def matchFilterFormat: Formatter[MatchFilterType] = new Formatter[MatchFilterType] {

  override def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) =
    data.get(key)
        .map(MatchFilterType.withName(_))
        .toRight(Seq(FormError(key, "error.required", Nil)))

  override def unbind(key: String, value: MatchFilterType) = 
    Map(key -> value.toString)
}
```

Then use `Forms.of` to create a `FieldMapping`:

```
Form(...,
     "mft" -> Forms.of[MatchFilterType],
     ...)
```

Bear in mind that `MatchFilterType.withName(_)` will thrown an exception if the string is not an enum member, so update the `bind` method to handle this as you need.

Comment: can you explain why I have to create this formatter? the theory behind it :)

Comment: How would I make this optional?

Comment: @Blankman to make it optional just wrap the mapping in an `optional`: `"mft" -> optional(Forms.of[MatchFilterType])`. You'll need to update `SearchRequest` to take an `Option[MatchFilterType]`.  For the theory see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#custom-binders-for-form-mappings

Comment: Is this generalizable? Someting like E:< Enumeration?

Comment: @ObjectiveTruth see below https://stackoverflow.com/a/63348335/241133

Answer (score 1):

A more generic approach:

```
def enumerationFormatter[E <: Enumeration](enum: E): Formatter[E#Value] = new Formatter[E#Value] {
  override def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], E#Value] =
    data.get(key).map(s => enum.withName(s)).toRight(Seq(FormError(key, "error.required", Nil)))
  override def unbind(key: String, value: E#Value): Map[String, String] = Map(key -> value.toString)
}
```

Which can then be used like:

```
object TestValues extends Enumeration {
  type TestValue = Value
  val Test: TestValue = Value
}
case class MyForm(testValue: TestValue)
object MyForm {
  implicit val testValueFormatter: Formatter[TestValue] = enumerationFormatter(TestValues)
  val form = Form(mapping("testValue" -> of[TestValue])(MyForm.apply)(MyForm.unapply))
}
```