# Play how to implement an implicit Writes or Format for a case class including an Enumeration

Tags: forms, scala, enums, playframework

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259710/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-playframework-form) shows how to bind an Enumeration to a form using a case class.

However in Play 2.7.3 this code fails with:

```
No Json serializer found for type jura.SearchRequest. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

When I implement the formatter:

```
object SearchRequest {
  implicit val searchRequestFormat: OFormat[SearchRequest] = Json.format[SearchRequest]
}
```

I get

> No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for
>   scala.Enumeration.Value in the implicit scope

*Should I be trying to write a formatter for the system scala.Enumeration type?

Or is there another way to implement a formatter when Enumerations are involved?*

Test case [here](https://github.com/jethrogillgren/play-samples).

Comment: `Writes.enumNameWrites` is provided. W/o the case class definition, I find weird to have `scala.Enumeration.Value` as property type, rather than `E#Value` (for some `E <: scala.Enumeration`)

Comment: Are you in control of `SearchRequest` and is it not used by other libraries?

Comment: @pme Yes, in control. It'll be used with Slick. Thanks!

Comment: Are you also interested in solutions replacing `scala.Enumeration` entirely?

Comment: @pme Yes.  As I understand it the Jury's out on whether we should use the Enumeration class or just use case classes..  Any method which provides enum-like functionality would work - but the preference would be for the best-practice approach, which I took to mean using actual Enumerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use for any Enumeration this Library: **[enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum)**

With **Dotty** there will be great *Enumerations*, but until then I think moving to *enumeratum*  is the best way handling Enumerations in *Scala*. See also [Dotty - Enumerations](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/enums.html).

As a bonus there is a `play-json` Extension, see [Play JSON Extension](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#play-json).

With this your code would look like this:

```
import enumeratum.{ PlayJsonEnum, Enum, EnumEntry }

sealed trait SearchRequest extends EnumEntry

object SearchRequest extends Enum[SearchRequest] with PlayJsonEnum[SearchRequest] {

  val values = findValues

  case object SuperRequest  extends SearchRequest
  case object SimpleRequest extends SearchRequest
  ..
}
```

In essence `PlayJsonEnum[SearchRequest]` does all the work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  This looks much better than the standard Enumerations.  One minor change is to use PlayEnum instead of PlayJsonEnum, as that includes both JSON and Form support.  And in the form mapping you can then use `"myEnum" ->  MyEnum.formField,`

Answer (score 1):

To write the enum as a string as cchantep says you can use **Writes.enumNameWrites**, we specifically use to read and write the ID. Therefore we have an EnumFormat in the package global for enums:

```
package object enums {

  implicit def reads[E <: Enumeration](enum: E): Reads[E#Value] = new Reads[E#Value] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[E#Value] = json match {
      case JsNumber(s) =>
        try {
          JsSuccess(enum.apply(s.toInt))
        } catch {
          case _: NoSuchElementException => JsError(s"Enumeration expected of type: '${enum.getClass}', but it does not appear to contain the value: '$s'")
        }
      case _ => JsError("Number value expected")
    }
  }

  implicit def writes[E <: Enumeration]: Writes[E#Value] = new Writes[E#Value] {
    def writes(v: E#Value): JsValue = JsNumber(v.id)
  }

  implicit def formatID[E <: Enumeration](enum: E): Format[E#Value] =
    Format(reads(enum), writes)


  def readsString[E <: Enumeration](enum: E): Reads[E#Value] = new Reads[E#Value] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[E#Value] = json match {
      case JsString(s) => {
        try {
          JsSuccess(enum.withName(s))
        } catch {
          case _: NoSuchElementException => JsError(s"Enumeration expected of type: '${enum.getClass}', but it does not appear to contain the value: '$s'")
        }
      }
      case _ => JsError("String value expected")
    }
  }

  implicit def writesString[E <: Enumeration]: Writes[E#Value] = new Writes[E#Value] {
    def writes(v: E#Value): JsValue = JsString(v.toString)
  }

  implicit def formatString[E <: Enumeration](enum: E): Format[E#Value] =
    Format(readsString(enum), writesString)
}
```

And used:

```
object SearchRequest extends Enumeration(1) {
  type SearchRequest = Value

  val ONE /*1*/ , TWO /*2*/ , ETC /*n*/ = Value

  implicit val searchRequestFormat: Format[SearchRequest] = formatID(SearchRequest)
}
```

Comment: It should not be required, and this generic `Writes` should be resolved from the implicit scope when using the `Json.writes/format` macro to "generate"/derive instance for the case class .

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this code seems to give a type mismatch,
our format is `play.api.libs.json.Format[models.MatchFilterType.Value]` but Play expects a `play.api.data.format.Formatter[models.MatchFilterType.Value] "mft" -> Forms.of[MatchFilterType](matchFilterTypeFormat)`.   I have made a test case here https://github.com/jethrogillgren/play-samples/blob/2.7.x/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/app/models/Search.scala thanks for any further help!  Note SearchRequest is the case class, which uses enum MatchFilterType.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Enumeration Object

```
implicit object MatchFilterTypeFormatter extends Formatter[MatchFilterType.Value] {
    override val format = Some(("format.enum", Nil))
    override def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = {
      try {
        Right(MatchFilterType.withName(data.get(key).head))
      } catch {
        case e:NoSuchElementException =>  Left(Seq(play.api.data.FormError(key, "Invalid MatchFilterType Enumeration")))
      }
    }
    override def unbind(key: String, value: MatchFilterType.Value) = {
      Map(key -> value.toString)
    }
  }
  implicit val matchFilterTypeFormat = new Format[MatchFilterType.MatchFilterType] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(MatchFilterType.withName(json.as[String]))
    def writes(myEnum: MatchFilterType.MatchFilterType) = JsString(myEnum.toString)
  }
```

And then the Formatter/Controller given in the question will work.

A working test case is [here](https://github.com/jethrogillgren/play-samples/blob/workingversion/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/app/models/Search.scala#L17).

Comment: An improvement would be to make this generic, so that it doesn't need duplicating for each enum you wish to use.